# I get an error 404 for a JSP file in WEB-INF without any message

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-404

I started to do a project in eclipse ide using tomcat server. So apparently i did not get any errors in jsps and servlets.
But i dont get any output and it display 404 error without any msg

> heres what i tried
> I uninstall and reinstall the tomcat server
> Give web.xml file to the correct path
> Imported all the java files
> Change the tomcat-users.xml code
>
> can someone pls help me with this error?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSEh9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think your Jsp file is not positioned under the Web-Info folder try TO charge the position of the Jsp file right there

Answer (score 0):

When we request a resource on the server through a browser,
it may be a JSP or servlet. If the resource to be accessed does not exist, a 404 error will be generated.

Due to following reason we get 404.

1. The URL is not handled by any java servlets.

   ```
   Please check for URL mapping in servlet classes.
   ```
2. Java servlet forwarding to a resource that does not exist

   ```
   Please correct the forward path in java code
   ```
3. Please check URL is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

In every web application there are some files, which should not be accessible from the web. In the case of the Servlet Specification, the `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` are not **directly** accessible through HTTP:

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named `WEB-INF`. This directory contains all things related to the application that aren’t in the document root of the application. Most of the `WEB-INF` node is not part of the public document tree of the application.

(from the [Servlet specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#directory-structure))

Just move your `*.jsp` file out of the `WEB-INF` directory and you'll be able to access it directly from your browser.